# Change TextInput Style on Focus React Native Paper

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-paper

First of all, I've researched through other posts and find many solutions but nothing work in React Native Paper ?

I need change TextInput Style on Focus in React Native Paper
[image]

Comment: You can add extra style on hover event to the selected textarea

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const { isActive } = this.state;
const customStyle = isActive ? styles.customText : {};


<TextInput
    label='Email'
    value={this.state.text}
    style={customStyle}
    onFocus={() => this.setState({ isActive: true, })}
    onBlur={() => this.setState({ isActive: false, })}
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the onBlur and onFocus that come with `TextInput` from `react-native-paper` the methods to change the styling.
Example:
to be placed in the `render` method

```
const { isActive } = this.state;
const customStyle = isActive ? styles.customText : {};
```

the component as placed in the return function

```
<TextInput
    label='Email'
    value={this.state.text}
    style={customStyle}
    onFocus={() => this.setState({ isActive: true, })}
    onBlur={() => this.setState({ isActive: false, })}
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra style on hover event to the selected textarea and remove that style onBlur, This can be achieved by using state value check as given below

```
class Myclass extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      focus : false,
      name  : ''
    }
}

render() {    
    return (

            <TextInput 
                style={[styles.mText,this.state.focus? styles.textFocus : null]}
                placeholder=""
                onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ name:value })}
                value={this.state.name}
                onFocus={()=>{this.setState({focus:true})}}
                onBlur={()=>{this.setState({focus:false})}}
            />

    );
}

}
```

Style for textinput is given below

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  mText:{
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    padding:5,
    height:40,
    width:300,
    borderColor:"#333",
    borderStyle:"solid",
    borderWidth:1,
  },

  textFocus:{
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    borderColor:"#5d05d5",
  },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

just add theme in the TextInput tag

```
<TextInput theme={{ colors: { primary: "color of your wish" } }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro You can use activeOutlineColor="" it'll  change your outline text color as well as your outline(border). If you want to set outline color diffrent than you can use outlineStyle={borderWidth: 1, borderColor: ""} whatever you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).